# Block element with specific width but also width-adaptable for long words in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to make `<div>` with specific max-width (for example 100px) and when this element contains some long words ( more then 100px) make it width-adaptable for these words, without word breaking or hiding overflow, just like on the attached picture.
[image: Example issue]

Is this possible with pure HTML & CCS ?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Nope...CSS styles content...it can't detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we have to make the `<div>` element shrink-to-fit. This can be achieved by `float`ing the element or `display`ing it as an `inline-block` element.

Then, we can add a `min-width` of `100px` to the element to set a minimum width.

For instance:

```css
div {
  display   : inline-block;
  min-width : 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this is not what i want. to clarify my requirements, an element can have a MAXIMUM width of 100px OR width equal to the longest word if it is longer than 100px. But it is not possible to do that without using JS, is it?

Comment: @user1827257 Then you must update the question to emphasize that. And I'm afraid that there's no possible CSS solution to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a fix width on a div it won't be adaptable. You would have to use JavaScript to watch for text.

Alternatively don't use a fixed width but use min-width:100px and it will grow beyond 100 when needed but always be a minimum of 100px